# Get attachments based on a custom post types post ID

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I don't know if this is possible but I'll try to explain.

I have a custom post type (creatives) and a taxonomy (image-sort). Every post in the CPT is a person (a creative). They can upload images and sort them by choosing which categories (the 'image-sort' taxonomy) they belong to.

There are multiple creatives, and they will post images to different categories. Some to all of them, some to just a few.

Every creative have their own page with a dynamic listing of which categories they have posted content to. My problem is though that if one creative have posted to 'cat-1' and 'cat-2' everybody get that listed out on their respective page. What I want is to only show 'cat-1' and 'cat-2' on the creative which has posted to those categories. If another creative has posted to 'cat-1' and 'cat-3' I only want those two to appear on his page.

Does this make sense?

```
<ul>
<?php
    $terms = get_terms('image-sort');
    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error($terms) ) :
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
?>
<li><a href="?term=<?php esc_attr_e($term->slug); ?>"><?php esc_html_e($term->name); ?</a></li>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand you, but if i do, try replacing this line:

```
$terms = get_terms('image-sort');
```

with the following line:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'image-sort');
```

**EDIT**

Try fetching the terms with the following piece of code:

```
<?php

// get all attachments of the current post
$attachments = get_children('post_parent=' . get_the_ID() . '&post_type=attachment&post_status=any&posts_per_page=-1');

// we're saving the terms here
$all_terms = array();

// looping through all attachments
foreach( $attachments as $attachment) {
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($attachment->ID, 'image-sort');
    if ($terms) {
        // looping through all attachment terms and adding them to the main array
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $all_terms[$term->term_id] = $term;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you might be on to it, but unfortunately that didn't do the trick. What I want is to list out categories based on which categories the current post ID (CPT post) has added content to. By content I mean pictures they upload to categories as they see fit, so there may be 3 different categories, but one post may only have pictures in two of the cats, and another post may have in all three.

Comment: This is not quite clear, i think further clarification is needed. Can you please clarify what you mean by "categories current post ID has added content to" and "pictures they upload to categories as they see fit", and "one post may only have pictures in two cats"?

Comment: Yes. I have one Custom Post Type (creatives) and one Taxonomy (image-sort). In the creatives CPT I have several posts (creatives). Every one of the creatives have different attachments (images/pictures/videos) associated with them. These attachments are stored in categories created by the taxonomy (image-sort). Those categories can be "editorial", "commercial", "film" and so on. What I try to do is to list only the categories a creative have filed his/her attachments in. So one creative may have only images filed in "editorial", but another has images and film in "editorial" and "film" e.g.

Comment: It is still not clear how you relate attachments with categories, also when you say attachments, do you mean the post type attachment?

Comment: Yes. It is the post type attachment. Regular uploads to the media library. The taxonomy image-sort is a way to "tag" the attachments so I can filter them on output.

Comment: I think i understood. I edited my answer above and added some code (untested) - feel free to give it a try.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! It's almost there. It lists the categories right now, but it only lists one, not multiple if there are attachments in that post in different categories.

Comment: This is weird. In the code the $all_terms is supposed to contain all terms from all attachments of the current post. Perhaps you're using $terms instead of $all_terms?

Comment: My bad. It works as far as I can see. I just had to figure out how to write my output after the foreach section. Thanks again. You probably saved my day!

Comment: I'm glad i was able to help. Have fun!